# How to add new key value to existing List Map object in java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

In below code am getting map of documents i want to add new key & value to documents object.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getDocuments() {
    String sql = "Select * from docs";
    List<Map<String, Object>> Documents = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForList(sql);
    return Documents;
}
```

Output:

```
[{Id=DOC10,Name=Test Document,Date=10-12-17}],
[{Id=DOC11,Name=Sample Document,Date=15-12-17}]
```

How can I add a new k,v to this `List<Map>` object so that output looks like this?

```
[{Id=DOC10,Name=Test Document,Date=10-12-17,Access=true}],
[{Id=DOC11,Name=Sample Document,Date=15-12-17,Access=true}]
```

Comment: You are using a `Map<String,Object>` so simply with `put("Access", true)`, now, this should be done from the `ResultSet` to get the value `true/false` I believe. You could simply do a `select *, true as Access from docs` depending on the logic of your method.

Comment: This seems like a rather strange request.  Typically you would not be manually adding data to a SQL result set.  Maybe you can explain why you think you need to be doing this.

Comment: I would make that variable lowercase per Java specs e.g. "`document`".

Comment: i want to show documents having field access= true in UI using angularjs so i need to add this new key,value pairs at server side

Comment: @user1909711 but where is that value stored ?

Answer (score 6):

You can just iterate through the list and add a new key value pair to each map:

```
for(Map<String, Object> map : Documents){
     map.put("Access", true);
}
```

Comment: I iterated already but throwing the exception as java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Java 8 version: `documents.forEach(doc -> doc.put("Access", true));`

Comment: @user1909711 It seems that the list or maps are being modified by some other thread. Try to use an iterator or a normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, depending on what `jdbcTemplateObject.queryForList(sql);` do is to add the value in your query.

```
select *, 1 as Access from docs
```

this seems to iterate on each column to insert it in the `Map`.

NOTE: the query is not necessarily DBMS independent ! Boolean is not really a SQL type

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the List> Documents & get Map Object and put key value pair in that Map object
e,g

```
List<Map<String, Object>> Documents = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForList(sql);
    for (Map<String, Object> map : Documents) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
```